# Replace whole cell with formula if it contains particular string

Tags: excel, vba

I want to Replace whole cell with  a formula  if it contains particular string (searchText) , but find and replace is not just replacing **searchText** with formula and not removing other contents of cell.

Can anyone help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use asterisk to mask other cell contents. So you have to search and replace the following line: `*searchText*`.

[image]

In VBA that would look like this:

```
Cells.Replace What:="*searchText*", Replacement:="=1+1"
```